# Windows Form Custome Tool: Combobox with Checkbox items

Tags: .net, winforms

I need a control that acts like a combobox but has checkbox items in it.

I don't see any tool like this.  What's the best way to 'roll your own'?

Comment: what is your intended use for this "control"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a common request, check out [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/checkedcombobox.aspx).  Find others by googling "checkedcombobox".